# How can I convert this specific coordinates?

Tags: r, maps

UPDATED QUESTION :

From an initial table of points with X / Y coordinates  I want to convert these coordinates with R.

From this (in the same orders of magnitude) :

[image]

To this :

[image]

Sorry and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way, but is seems to get the job done

**sample data**

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- tibble(
  etab = c("Guadeloupe","Martinique","Guyane","La Reunion","Corse"),
  x = c(658750, 709950, 357950, 365750, 659245),
  y = c(1796550,1609550,539650,7670150,6856374),
  espg = c(2989,2989,2972,2975,2154)
)
#          etab      x       y espg
# 1: Guadeloupe 658750 1796550 2989
# 2: Martinique 709950 1609550 2989
# 3:     Guyane 357950  539650 2972
# 4: La Reunion 365750 7670150 2975
# 5:      Corse 659245 6856374 2154
```

**code**

```
library(data.table)
library(sf)
#split data.frma by espg
L <- split(setDT(mydf), by = "espg")
# Loop over list L, make data an sf-object and transform to WGS84
L2 <- lapply(seq_along(L), function(x) {
  data <- L[[x]]
  cur_esgp <- as.numeric(names(L)[x])
  st_as_sf(data, coords = c("x","y")) %>%
    sf::st_set_crs(cur_esgp) %>%
    st_transform(4326)
} )
# bind the lists' elements back together
final <- purrr::reduce(L2, sf:::rbind.sf)
```

**output**

```
mapview::mapview(final)
```

[image]